# Batch file to convert military time to standard time from a text file to a new text file

Tags: batch-file

What I am trying to do is convert Military times in a text file and export standard time to a new text file through batch if possible I have not be able to figure out how to do this

Comment: 'military time' and 'standard time' are ambiguous. Could you specify the input and desired output formats. Also it would be good to see what you have tried so far

Comment: this is the input would like export to be the same or similar: 
03/22/2015  Sunday  1430-2300  1645-1700  1830-1900  2115-2130   
03/23/2015  Monday  1400-2230  1615-1630  1845-1915  2015-2030

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for but you could try something like importing a time to a variable (`set x < time.txt`) and then check if it's over 12 to avoid unnecessary conversion (`if %x% =< 12`) and divide the ones that aren't by 2 (`x = %x% / 2`)

I don't know how well this would work seeing as I haven't worked with batch and it seems it would only work with hours. Anyway, I hope this helps.